# Kali Linux Hydra question

Tags: brute-force, kali-linux, hydra

Recently a friend of mine coded a website and he asked me to brute force it to test it 
HTML code of the page trying to use hydra on 
https://pastebin.com/D2iQXrNb (use Pastebin because I don't know how to put HTML code in here)

so I used this hydra syntax `hydra -l '' -P /root/Downloads/a url.com http-post-form "/admin.php:pass=^PASS^:F=Invalid input!" -t16`
the problem is im getting too much green lines (false positives)
so am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to specify a form that specifies an input named `pass`.

However, the HTML you linked to specifies an input named `Password`.

Secondly, it is may be good to try a less strict failure condition `:F=Invalid` instead of `:F=Invalid input!`, as sometimes encoding issues can cause a match to be missed.

In short, try:
hydra -l '' -P /root/Downloads/a url.com http-post-form "/admin.php:pass=^PASS^:F=Invalid input!" -t16

Also, it is not clear from your question if you have too many "greens", or all "greens"?

In short, try:

```
hydra -l '' -P /root/Downloads/a url.com http-post-form "/admin.php:Password=^PASS^:F=Invalid" -t16
```

Alternatively, start logging the requests and responses to see what is going on.